# ZF2 Generate navigation using zfcrbac zfcUser and hierarchical role strategy

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zfcuser, zfc-rbac

I begin in zf2 and i have to handle Many to Many permissions/roles. Using [ZfcRbac](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac/tree/master/src/ZfcRbac).

So i make a mapping with User / Hierarchical Role (table name= role) / permissions

And i make some guards with deny policy.

My guard, mapping, database, are ok.

My HierarchicalRole Entity looks like :

```
class HierarchicalRole implements HierarchicalRoleInterface
```

And it's, for now the same as the original given by Bakura.

My user Entity looks like this :

```
class User extends ZfcUserEntity implements IdentityInterface
```

with

```
    /**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="HierarchicalRole")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *     name="user_role_linker",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="idUser")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $roles;
```

and roles are built in constructor by :

```
function __construct() {
    $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

With zend developper tools i can see that `ZfcRbac\Collector\RbacCollector` show all i want for the actual logged user (permission, children, main role etc...).

My question is : **How to generate a dynamic navigation, for a user wich can only see links that is granted to access ?**. And also check connexion when the user not logged and hide it when he's logged...

I'm a newbie yet, but if possible it would be great to have an example well explained for doing a good dynamic navigation using this module.

**EDIT (may 28)**
So far i always seek for a solution, my tries didn't helped me yet..
You can find one  here :
[Spiffy navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23032619/use-spiffy-navigation-with-zfcrbac-module)
Still not working perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll show you how ZfcRbac can work with (ZF2) Zend/Navigation.
You have definition of permissions in database, that's why I'll omit this section.

Define your navigation adding pages and permissions:

config/global.phpPHP:

```
return array(
        'navigation' => array(
            'default' => array(
                array(
                    'label' => 'Contracts',
                    'route' => 'contract',
                    'action' => 'list',
                    'permission' => 'contract.list',
                    'pages' => array(
                         array(
                            'label'  => 'New contract',
                            'route'  => 'contract',
                            'action' => 'add',
                            'permission' => 'contract.add',
                         )
                     )
                )
            )
        ),
        'service_manager' => array(
            'factories' => array(
                'navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',
            )
        )
    );
```

Create a Listener (/module/Application/src/Application/Authorization/RbacListener.php):

```
<?php

namespace Application\Authorization;

use Zend\EventManager\EventInterface;
use Zend\Navigation\Page\AbstractPage;
use ZfcRbac\Service\AuthorizationServiceInterface;

class RbacListener
{
    /**
     * @var AuthorizationServiceInterface
     */
    protected $authorizationService;

    /**
     * @param AuthorizationServiceInterface $authorizationService
     */
    public function __construct(AuthorizationServiceInterface $authorizationService)
    {
        $this->authorizationService = $authorizationService;
    }

    /**
     * @param  EventInterface $event
     * @return bool|void
     */
    public function accept(EventInterface $event)
    {
        $page = $event->getParam('page');

        if (!$page instanceof AbstractPage) {
            return;
        }

        $permission = $page->getPermission();

        if (is_null($permission)) {
            $event->stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }

        $event->stopPropagation();

        return $this->authorizationService->isGranted($permission);
    }
}
```

Create a Factory for the RbacListener (/module/Application/src/Application/Factory/RbacListenerFactory.php):

```
<?php

namespace Application\Factory;

use Application\Authorization\RbacListener;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class RbacListenerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $authorizationService = $serviceLocator->get('ZfcRbac\Service\AuthorizationService');

        return new RbacListener($authorizationService);
    }
}
```

Add your RbacListenerFactory to your ServiceManager (/module/Application/config/module.config.php):

```
<?php

return array(
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Application\Authorization\RbacListener' => 'Application\Factory\RbacListenerFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Attach an event to the isAllowed method of the Zend Navigation View Helper (And finally attach an event to the isAllowed method of the Zend Navigation View Helper):

```
<?php

public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $application        = $event->getApplication();
    $eventManager       = $application->getEventManager();
    $sharedEventManager = $eventManager->getSharedManager;
    $serviceManager     = $application->getServiceManager();
    $rbacListener       = $serviceManager->get('Application\Authorization\RbacListener');

    $sharedEventManager->attach(
        'Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\AbstractHelper',
        'isAllowed',
        array($rbacListener, 'accept')
    );
}
```

To render menu in view or layout:

```
<?php echo $this->navigation('navigation')->menu(); ?>
```

I'm using this code and it works quite well. It's based on:

- http://blog.webdevilopers.net/check-zend-navigation-page-permissions-with-zfcrbac/
- http://puzzlingcodes.blogspot.com/2015/05/check-permissions-in-zf2-zendnavigation.html